# Including Jquery in my html

Tags: jquery, html

I am having trouble figuring out how to include my jquery script into my index.php

script.js

```
$("#toggle-content").click(function () {$("#mel").slideToggle(); });
```

Comment: Did you include jQuery script in your page... did you add the script in a dom ready handler

Comment: see http://plnkr.co/edit/sucVQOHKnvXPwUFJR0Xh?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Simply, save your file in script.js, and copy this code at very bottom of your index.php. Notice script.js and index.php should be in the same directory.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

**or**

paste this in your index.php

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
$("#toggle-content").click(function () {$("#mel").slideToggle(); });
});
    </script>
```